# How to configure EC2 autoscaling based on multiple limits on same metric?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My primary requirement is as follows:

When CPU consumption on an instance exceeds 50 % then adjust capacity of autoscaling group to 5 instances, when CPU consumption exceeds 80% then adjust capacity to 10 instances.

However if I use cloudwatch alarms to set capacity I can imagine the following race condition:

- 5 instances exist
- CPU consumption exceeds 80 %
- Alarm is triggered
- Capacity is changed to 19 instances
- CPU consumption drops below 50 %
- Eventually CPU consumption again exceeds 50% but now capacity will be changed to 5 instances (which is something I don't want to happen)

So what I would ideally like to happen is that in response to alarm triggers I would like to ensure that capacity is altleast the corresponding threshold.

I am aware that this can be done by manually setting the capacity through AWS SDK - which could be triggered in response to lifecycle events monitored by a supervisor, but is there a better approach, preferably one that does not require setting up additional supervisors or webhooks for alarms ?

Comment: At first look it seems like the logic is a little too much for the simple autoscaling mechanism (I may be proved wrong). I'd be tempted to investigate a lambda function triggered by cloudwatch sns notifications. Which can contain much more in depth logic.

Comment: AWS lambda seems to be a great solution. Thank you for pointing that out. If you can add that as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Great to hear it - I've added it as an answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking into an AWS lambda function, triggered by an SNS message from cloudwatch - it should give you free reign to put as much logic into the scaling decision as you want.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

A general approach is to fine grain the scaling actions:
Do not jump that big:

```
if the ASG avg CPU is over 70% > Add an instance
if the ASG avg CPU is over 90% > Add "n" instances
if the ASG avg CPU is under 40% > remove an instance
if the ASG avg CPU is under 10% > remove "n" instance
```

All of these values are the last 5 mins AVG. So if you have a really fast pike, you need more aggressive scaling. So in half an hour you can easily add 6 servers or even more.

Also scaling works better with higher numbers. So if your system needs only 1-3 instances, it may make sense to decrease the instance size so you can have 2-6 instances. It give some extra flexibility to your system.

But again, the question is, what is your expected load? Big pikes or an expected up and down during the day?

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I was expecting a significant increase of load during a few peak hours. After a bit of exploration I currently think scheduled scaling is a better approach for handling that, while leaving alarm based scheduling only for handling sudden unexpected increase in workloads.

Comment: If you know when your load comes, scheduled pre-warming(upscaling) is a good approach! Also consider other services, like Cloudfront, which may decrease the load on your servers.